# FileReader upload File through Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, filereader

I have an old Rails form that I want to translate into Ember Data:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What gets stored in the database needs to match what I currently do.  Users can upload files of all types, not just binary.  I choose a particular image, and in the database, the file data begins with this:

```
[1] pry(#<AttachmentsController>)> @attachment.data
=> "\xC3\xBF\xC3\x98\xC3\xBF\xC3\xA2\x02\x1CICC_PROFILE\x00
```

I want to convert the form to upload using javascript and Ember.JS Data, not form submission.  The javsacript which uploads my data is this:

```
var attachment = this.store.createRecord('attachment');
attachment.set('data', data);
attachment.save();
```

The problem is data.  When it gets to the server, it's different than how it was for the form.  I've tried reading the data in multiple ways:

readAsBinaryString produced a different string:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
// Note: readAsBinaryString is DEPRECATED
[1] pry(#<AttachmentsController>)> @attachment.data
=> "\xC3\xBF\xC3\x98\xC3\xBF\xC3\xA2\x02\x1CICC_PROFILE\x00
```

Read as text would occassionally crash when uploading a binary file

```
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
// crashes
```

readAsDataURL produced results that didn't match what I need to store in my database

```
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
[1] pry(#<AttachmentsController>)> @attachment.data
=> "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtb
```

readAsArrayBuffer looks promising, but I'm not sure what I should do with the arrayBuffer to send

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. Please add readAsBinaryString result and raw image data (an excerpt will do).
2. Please tell us what that reader is.
3. Please tell us what `data` variable in your JS example holds.

Comment: I'm assuming you're following this blog post. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/15/client-side-file-processing-ember-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Decode Data URI

You can base64 decode the version provided by readAsDataURL. Here is a naive implementation.

```
require 'base64'
decoded_result = Base64.decode64(data.gsub('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''))
```

There is a library for properly [processing Data URIs in Ruby](https://github.com/dball/data_uri)

### Use a Normal Form for Uploading File

#### Links to Code

There is a library for [uploading images in Ember](https://github.com/trick17media/t17-ember-upload),
please read its code. You're particularly interested in these areas.

[Input View for handling events](https://github.com/trick17media/t17-ember-upload/blob/master/lib/t17-ember-upload/upload-input-view.js#L10)

[What to upload](https://github.com/trick17media/t17-ember-upload/blob/master/lib/t17-ember-upload/upload-mixin.js#L88)

[How to create form](https://github.com/trick17media/t17-ember-upload/blob/master/lib/t17-ember-upload/upload-mixin.js#L43)

[How to upload](https://github.com/trick17media/t17-ember-upload/blob/master/lib/t17-ember-upload/upload-mixin.js#L57)

#### Excerpt

```
App.FileView = Ember.View.extend({
  MultipleInput: Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    classNames: 'files',
    attributeBindings: ['type', 'multiple'],
    type: 'file',
    multiple: 'multiple',
    change: function(e) {
      var input = e.target;
      var file = input.files[0];
      var fd = new FormData();

      fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);
      fd.append('file', file)

      $.ajax({
        url: UPLOAD_URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: this.get('requestHeaders'),
        xhr: function() {
          return $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        }
      })
    }
  }),
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if I use FormData and $.ajax, the data store in Ember has no idea that my attachment record has been created and saved to the server, so my datastore is out of sync with what's in the database on the server.  The Base64, although I would prefer not to use it, seems to be the only viable solution.  What I ended up doing is using FileReader to get an ArrayBuffer, translated the ArrayBuffer to a Base64 encoded string, attached this to my ember data object, and translated it back into binary on the server.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: All I can say is, swimming against current is fun at start, exhausting few hours in and strangling after _enough_ time. In your shoes, I wouldn't store images in DB, try to communicate raw binary data over network or hack a custom solution out of a tool that wasn't designed for my requirements.

Comment: It's strange that uploads aren't a main concern of ember data. doesn't sound like a strange requirement for web-apps to me :\

Comment: With uploads, an `/events` endpoint and being able to push custom code to server a JSONAPI server becomes CouchDB. @K maybe CouchDB is a better choice?